# Trying to return my list as a table in Python

Tags: python, list

So I have a list with a bunch of values;

```
filmList = []
filmList.append(['FM01', 'Stealth', 135, 80])
filmList.append(['FM02', 'Supernova', 90, 15])
filmList.append(['FM03', 'Robin Hood', 100, 85])
filmList.append(['FM04', 'Rollerball', 70, 26])

return filmList
```

that I want to display something like this;

```
ID     Title               Budget       Box-office
--------------------------------------------------
FM01   Stealth             135          80 
FM02   Supernova           90           15 
FM03   Robin Hood          100          85
```

I'm a total noob to python, so any help would be appreciated <3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data)

Comment: @ThePyGuy as far as I can tell my code is doing something totally different to that

Comment: But the answer is already there